# MDVA-36832: Images duplicate on pages with 768px view width

Tags: image, magento, duplicates

I am using Magento 2.3.4 and have a problem with the site builder displaying 2 images. There is a patch available but it does not support Magento version 2.3.4.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

MDVA-36832: Images duplicate on pages with 768px view width
https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402390637453-MDVA-36832-Images-duplicate-on-pages-with-768px-view-width

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento displays the search results through the template;

> app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

You wanted to change that then the best thing you could do is follow the advice in the following link and designate a custom template to display your results by copying and renaming the list.phtml file;

Magento design update to replace list.phtml on search results page only

You could then customise it however you want. The section you would change is the following code which, as you can see ( the ->resize(135) part) is resizing your small product image to 135px. Change that to 400 and assuming the small image itself is not smaller than 400px wide then it wants to be pixellated.

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```